# Do chain Pressens stack?

Tags: remember-me

As far as I understand it, Chain Pressens (the blue ones) duplicate the effects of the Pressen that they are chained to (e.g. Chain Pressens linked to Damage Pressens deal more damage, linked to Regen Pressens heal more, etc.). What happens if you link a Chain Pressen to another Chain Pressen?

Example:

> Damage -> Chain -> Chain

What effect would the second Chain Pressen have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It increases the effect of the link at the beginning of the chain. So in your example, the damage would be greater than if it was only one chain.

Note that it's not mere duplication; it duplicates the previous effect but with a little "more". So your chain would do damage, then damage+, then damage++. I only rented the game, so I don't have it in front of me to check what the multiplier was, but I don't believe it's as high as 2x, it's just damage plus some.